# JSON in iOS parse

Tags: ios, json

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *dictionary=[responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *dic=[dictionary valueForKey:@"data"];

 for (int a=0; a<dic.count; a++) {
        NSInteger z=(NSInteger)a;
        NSLog(@"%@",[[dic objectAtIndex:a] objectForKey:@"nom"]);
    }
```

this is the file

```
{"data":[ "",{"id":"1","nom":"hello","message":["",{"id":1,"nom":"dad"}]}, {"id":"2","nom":"hi","message":["",{"id":"1","nom":"marie"},{"id":"2","nom":"bob‌​"}]} ] }
```

When I want to parcour my json file, I saw the problem whith variable "a" in `objectAtIndex` because it's an integer, but if I try value 5 for exemple it's work's perfect.

Can you help me please.

Comment: Please share the log of dictionary

Comment: yes im using #import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

Comment: I think Anupdas meant you should share the actual JSON data :)

Comment: What do you mean by problem? Does it crash? Throw an exception? Provide unexpected data?

Comment: this is the file {"data":[
         "",{"id":"1","nom":"hello","message":["",{"id":1,"nom":"dad"}]},
            {"id":"2","nom":"hi","message":["",{"id":"1","nom":"marie"},{"id":"2","nom":"bob"}]}
        ]
}

Comment: and when i use this NSLog(@"%@",[[dic objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"nom"]); it works and it give me hello

Comment: put this with format in your Question for see to all

Comment: but i want to loop for every element in data, and it doesn' work if i passe an int variable "a" to objectAtIndex it generate an tread and no result

Comment: Well, as you see your first object is just an empty string (`""`) and that is the problem (you try to get a value like it was a dictionary)

Comment: thank you so match alladinian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `data` array... The very first object is an empty string. So, you're trying to send an `objectForKey:` message to it (believing that is a dictionary) and you get a crash. You should either remove your object or implement a logic that would try to inspect each object before trying to pull a value.